# Can we run a batch file (.bat) from the shared path

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, windows, batch-file

I have a **shared path (like //servername/c$/batches/)** where all my batch files are located now I am writing an **web application in C# to run .bat files** from that application. I know way to do it when I have a physical path.
But here I dont have a physical path. Is it possible to do it.

EDIT# 1

I execute my bat files just by double clicking on them or open the cmd progam on the physical server and then navigate to the drive and execute the bat file.

EDIT #2

when I put UNC path the get the following error

I getting an error myprogram.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file. 9009

Comment: **What happens when you run it from the UNC path**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Batch files don't support UNC paths as their "current directory".  There's a hackish work around of doing:

```
pushd "%~dp0"
your batch stuff
popd
```

%~dp0 expands to the current (d)rive/(p)ath/(0)batchfilename

---

example:

ok. a Simple batch file:

```
pushd %~dp0
echo "Hello from batch land"
echo %~dp0
popd
```

put that on a server somewhere, and try to run it via a unc path:

```
C:\> \\server\share\test.bat
```

You'll get as output:

```
C:\>pushd \\server\share\

Z:\>echo Hello from batch land
Hello from batch land

Z:\>echo \\server\share\
\\server\share\

Z:\>popd

C:\>
```

Weird, but it works.

Comment: But that won't work if the share is actually on a different server, and you execute the batch file locally, doesn't it?

Comment: @Christian: This will work in all cases.  `pushd` supports UNC paths.

Comment: Sorry for being persistent, but I don't quite get it. Assume you run `\\remote\c$\batches\foo.cmd` from your local box. How is `%~dp0` supposed to be expanded? The actual path (c:\batches\foo.cmd in this case) does not exist on your local box, but is the non-UNC path *on the server*.

Comment: I dont want to modify existing bat files. But tell me way that I can do it in C# code

Comment: Oddly enough, it creates a temporary share mount (on my win7 box, it comes out as Z: drive), runs the script, and then unmounts. That lets the batch run off a unc path, though it's still allocating a drive letter.

Comment: I like how pushd "%~dp0" works. I am using ProcessStartInfo to the start executing the .bat files. Tell me a way if i can add this as an arguments

Comment: @Christian.K: It will expand as `\\remote\c$\batches\`.

Comment: @MarcB: That's the only way it can possibly do that, since it can't `cd` to the path.

Comment: @Marc B: Indeed, that is what it says [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317379) as well. Thanks for trying :-)

Answer (score 0):

That's called a **UNC path**.
You can use it just like any other path.

However, the user that your ASP.Net code is running as must have read access to the network share.

Comment: even though i open the bat file through the UNC path, it just flickers but its not executing the code inside it.

Comment: Just to add to your answer: CMD.EXE does not support UNC paths as "current directory", so a `cd \\whatever\..` will not work in batch files.

Comment: @Praneeth: You have a current-directory issue.  You need to fix the `.bat` file so that it works from a different current directory.

Comment: @Chrisitan, I agree with you. Now how to make it work for my case?

Comment: I have all access and see there is no issue with current directory

Comment: @Praneeth: Execute it from an existing `cmd` window and see what it says.

Comment: I getting an error myprogram.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file. 9009

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact command you executed and the full output.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you **do** have a current-directory issue.
The `.bat` file is trying to run `myprogram.exe` from the current directory.

You can make a wrapper batch file on your local machine that maps the network share:

```
pushd \\server\c$\dir
call filename.bat
popd
```

You can put this wrapper file anywhere, then call it from your code.

Comment: Yes​​​​​​​​​​​.  And you need to understand why; you should not just blindly do this.

Comment: Its works but throw some internal exception...It still some dependencies inside the code